# How to use GET API in AngularJS and how to check if the API Key Value is equal to the value of data in any rows of table content in HTML?

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, get, angularjs-scope

How to display a text (i.e. ABCD) in SPAN tag if the API key value (numNum) matches with the value of any number (i.e row.number) ?

admin.html

```
<td ng-click="edit(row)">{{row.process}}<span>ABCD</span></td>
<td ng-click="edit(row)">{{row.number}}</td>
```

adminSvc.js

```
adminModule.factory("adminSvc", ["$http",
  function ($http) {
    return {
      checkNUM:function(numNum,company){
         return $http.get(proxyurl + "ApplicantProcessStatus?num=" + numNum + "&company=" + company);
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

adminCtrl.js

```
$scope.checkNUM = function(numNum){

}
```

I want to display ABCD in span tag, if the API Key (numNum)'s value matches with the row.number.

Note : there will be multiple numNum in perticular company. And the "row.number" will be multiple in rows, and that's the result coming from search result feature.

I do not know how to compare / check if there is any number similar between row.number and API (numNum).

Any help or suggestions are appreciated !

Comment: return statement has been provided. But, my expected solution is writing some lines of code in $scope.checkNUM = function(numNum){ }.
what should I write there to compare API key numNum's value with the "row.number" ???

Comment: There are three functions in the code, one in the controller, two in the service. Both functions in the service need a return statement.

Comment: my bad. I did return the second function in the service. It is now :  return $http.get(proxyurl + "ApplicantProcessStatus?num=" + numNum + "&company=" + company);

Comment: Any help on this ? : I do not know how to compare / check if there is any number similar between row.number and API (numNum).